# data type mismatch when trying to insert into an Access database from C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to insert into an access database. all the fields worked except for the "passwordx" field in which I get data type mismatch in criteria expression.

```
string commandSql = "INSERT INTO Members ( lastName, firstName, id, dob, phone, areaCodeNo, adress, cityNo, zipCode, email, active,passwordx) VALUES ( @lastName, @firstName, @id, @dob, @phone, @areaCodeNo, @adress, @cityNo, @zipCode, @email, @active,@passwordx); ";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(commandSql, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@lastName", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = mem.lastName;
command.Parameters.Add("@firstName", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = mem.firstName;
command.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = mem.id;
command.Parameters.Add("@dob", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = mem.dob;
command.Parameters.Add("@phone", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = mem.phone;
command.Parameters.Add("@areaCodeNo", OleDbType.Integer, 100).Value = mem.areaCodeNo;
command.Parameters.Add("@adress", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = mem.adress;
command.Parameters.Add("@cityNo", OleDbType.Integer, 100).Value = mem.cityNo;
command.Parameters.Add("@zipCode", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = mem.zipCode;
command.Parameters.Add("@email", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = mem.email;
command.Parameters.Add("@passwordx", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = mem.password;
command.Parameters.Add("@active", OleDbType.Boolean, 100).Value = mem.active;

connection.Open();
affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: does it matter that you have =mem.password and not =mem.passwordx

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing the table schema.

Comment: the password field is set as short text

Comment: what is the exact type of the column?

Comment: @Olivier  "Short Text" is the column type in Access.

Comment: Yes, but of which length is the column? Does it have a length of 100?

Answer (score 2):

Shuffle the last two parameters to match the sequence of your SQL:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@active", OleDbType.Boolean, 100).Value = mem.active;
command.Parameters.Add("@passwordx", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = mem.password;
```

And a *Boolean* doesn't have a length.

Comment: This is a good point. OleDB has positional parameters and ignores the parameter names. The wrong order means that the Boolean and VarChar parameters were mixed up, which explains the data type mismatch.